# In Excel, I am trying to calculate a percentage of two sums

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have a rather large dataset, 44 columns and about 8k to 9k rows each month. The table has every trip that our customers have either completed or not shown up for. I have started with a simple pivot table that outputs the following:

```
Customer_Name     comp     noshow
John James        4        1
Sue Stone         10       10
Chris Cole        25       0
```

The columns "comp" and "noshow" are simply counts of how many times in the dataset the column status is filled with the word *comp* or *noshow*.
What I am trying to do is create a third column that gives the percentage of trips that are noshow. This should be a simple Percentage = noshow / comp+noshow. What I was expecting is:

```
Customer_Name     comp     noshow     Percentage
John James        4        1          20%
Sue Stone         10       10         50%
Chris Cole        25       0          0%
```

What I'm getting are either the data for the same filled all the way down:
    =GETPIVOTDATA("Status",$DU$3,"Status","noshow","Clients full name","John James")/(GETPIVOTDATA("Status",$DU$3,"Status","comp","Clients full name","John James")+GETPIVOTDATA("Status",$DU$3,"Status","noshow","Clients full name","John James"))

With 410 distinct client names that can change each month, it's not practical to edit the string for the name either.

How can I accomplish what seems to me should be an easy task. (I am preparing my forehead now for something easy that I have missed!)

Comment: Why not just do `=C2/(B2+C2)` (this would be for John James) to calculate the percentage?

Comment: Yes, I was just hoping to be able to sort the calculated data to that I could put the higher percentages at the top, but at least this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this outside the pivot table the easiest way is to put in the formula manually.

If you click on the cell when inputting the formula you get `=getpivot...`, but you can manually type in `=B2` and it will still reference that cell even if it is within the pivot table.

Comment: Thank you! I think this will work. Unfortunately it will require adjusting each month depending on the number of clients in the array, and I can't sort it, but at least it will calculate and that's more than I was able to get before!

Answer (score 0):

With your pivot table already created, you can use the Calculated Field feature to create a sortable column within the Pivot Table.

In Excel 2013, the navigation is `PivotTable Tools > Analyze > Options > Fields, Items, & Sets > Calculated Field ...`

[image: Calculated Field]

The formula I used is the same as @gtwebb: `=noshow / (show +noshow )`

After you have your NoShowPercentage calculated field, you can sort the results by right clicking in the cell and selecting `Sort > Sort Largest to Smallest`

[image: Sort Largest to Smallest]

You can see in my screenshot, the most frequent no shows appear at the top.

I partially referenced [Mr. Excel's Calculating % on Two Columns](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/593999-calculating-percentage-two-columns-pivot-table.html) for the answer.